# DateTime [ Last week , Last month periods ]

Tags: asp.net

I need to setup last week , last month periods on changing dropdownlist

I'm making

```
        switch (DDL.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    // last week
                    this.TextBox3.Text = DateTime. //Previos week first day
                    this.TextBox4.Text = DateTime. //Previos week last day
                } break;
            case 1:
                {
                    // last mouth
                    this.TextBox3.Text = DateTime.// Previos month first day
                    this.TextBox4.Text = DateTime.// Previos month last day
                } break;
}
```

So is there some ways how can I select date values like I want ?

also , I've got AJAX calendar extender on text boxes

thank you.

Comment: do you want days of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ...) or the numbered day (1, 2 3, ...)

Comment: I want date , like 01.01.2010 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, I think:

```
int dayOfWeekNumber = (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

var previosWeekFirstDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7 - dayOfWeekNumber);

var previosWeekLastDay = previosWeekFirstDay.AddDays(6);

var previosMonthFirstDay = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
previosMonthFirstDay = previosMonthFirstDay.AddDays(-previosMonthFirstDay.Day + 1);

var previosMonthLastDay = previosMonthFirstDay.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(previosMonthFirstDay.Year, previosMonthFirstDay.Month) - 1);
```

Edited: see [Fredrik Mörk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93623/fredrik-mork) comment.

Comment: You may want to take into consideration some countries consider Sunday to be the first day of the week, while others use Monday (you can pick up that information from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`).